# Create Java program that creates and emails a file

Tags: java, email, netbeans

I created an application that collects and saves form data into a text file. Right now, the only way for my to receive that information is to have the user manually email the file over. I would like the application to automatically send the email when the user presses submit to make the process more user friendly. How would I go about doing that? Here is my code. I found a few things online, but everything seems to be outdated and no longer works. Thank you in advance!

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Thank you for joining BPA! A file has been created on your desktop. Please send the file to bpasignup@gmail.com to complete your registration.");
    String content = "," + FName.getText() + "," +
                     MName.getText() + "," + 
                     LName.getText() + "," + 
                     Email.getText() + "," + 
                     Phone.getText() + "," + 
                     SAddress.getText() + "," + 
                     City.getText() + "," +  
                     State.getSelectedItem() + "," +
                     ZIP.getText() + "," + 
                     Grade.getSelectedItem() + "," +
                     Shop.getSelectedItem() + "," +
                     HRoom.getText() + "," +
                     PName.getText() + "," +
                     PEmail.getText() + "," 
                     ;





try {

            File file = new File("c:/users/User/desktop/BPAsignup.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);    //step2: write it
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Unable to create file. Please contact your BPA director directly to resolve this issue.");
```

Comment: It's hard to believe you didn't find any useful tutorial to send an email with Java. Here is a [tutorial by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html). It's for a web application but the email part should be easily transferable.

Comment: That actually is exactly what I needed. That page wasn't appearing on any of my search results for some reason. Thank you, your a lifesaver!